# How do you make a 'like' query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I am new to Bookshelf JS and wanted to do a like query with the database. I read the documentation on their official website , but I am unable to figure this out.

The following is my code:

```
  1.  var DB = Bookshelf.initialize({
      client: 'mysql', 
      connection: config

     });

  2.  var User1=DB.Model.extend({

      tableName: 'applicationPrimary',

      });
```

3. Now I want to make a query like:

```
select * from applicationPrimary where id like '%2%' ;
```

4.I have tried the following:

```
   Model.User1.query(function(qb) {
   qb.where('id', 'LIKE', '%2%')

   }).fetch()
   .then(function(model) {
    console.log(model)

   });
```

The following is the manner I am initialising and setting up:

```
 1.    var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf');

    var config = {

     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'root',
     database: 'mydb',
     charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'

     };

    var DB = Bookshelf.initialize({

    client: 'mysql', 

    connection: config

  });

    module.exports.DB = DB;


 2. var DB = require('./db').DB;

     var User1 = DB.Model.extend({
     tableName: 'applicationPrimary',

     });


   module.exports = {
   User1: User1,

   };
```

and then I am using it as:

var Model = require('./model');

in the file I am using User1.

The above doesn't work and it throws an error saying there is no function called query.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for the `LIKE` is right, the problem is you should use `.where` on the `User1` object, not `.query` on `Model.User1`

```
User1.where('id', 'LIKE', '%2%').fetch().then(...)
```

Comment: I tried the following:
Model.User1.where('id', 'LIKE', query1).fetch().then(function(model) {
 });
Its throwing an error:
TypeError: Model.User1.where is not a function

Comment: Yes, use `User1`, not `Model.User1`

Comment: User1 is in another file called Model. Thats how i am referencing it.

Comment: Alright, could you update your post to show how the `Bookshelf` var is assigned and your exports?

Comment: Also, which version of Bookshelf.js are you using?

Comment: using 0.5 version of bookshelf.js .I have updated the post .please have a look.

Comment: Ok, your version is at least two and a half years late. API has probably changed since. Could you try updating to the latest (0.10.0 was released two weaks ago) and reporting back?

Comment: Yes ! `npm update <pkg>` updates the `package.json` and the `node_modules`.

Comment: So i guess I did update it
npm update bookshelf
It didnt show a change in the package.json though.
Still the same error persists.

Comment: Remove the line in package.json, delete the bookshelf folder in node_modules and `npm i -S bookshelf`

Comment: Could you manage to solve this? I am having the same issue however my bet is that it's a [Bookshelf bug](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1704)